# Power method to calculate eigenvectors

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices

I've implemented a program for computing eigenvectors of some random, symmetric, $N$x$N$ matrix using the power method.  I have found difficulty in calculating all $N$ eigenvectors consistently, almost every time the algorithm fails to converge for all $N$.  The Wikipedia page on the power method tells me this algorithm is not guaranteed to converge for all $N$ eigenvectors, can someone suggest a way for me to encourage convergence, at least in a majority of the cases?  Is this possible?  If not, can someone suggest a better algorithm for computing eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

Whole [books](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/eig_book_2ndEd.pdf) and fields of research are devoted to methods for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Properties of the matrix matter, a lot. The ideal method will depend on whether

- the matrices are symmetric or nonsymmetric,
- positive definite or indefinite,
- sparse or not sparse,
- you need all the eigenvalues/vectors or just a few,
- you have $O(1)$ access to the elements of the matrix or just the ability to apply it to vectors via a function call
- etc...

That said, at the core of most modern methods for finding all the eigenvalues of a generic matrix is the The [QR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) (the eigenvalue algorithm, not the related orthogonalization algorithm). The methods most used in practice such as the [Arnoldi iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi%27s_algorithm) (or [Lanczos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_iteration) for symmetric problems) are basically a 2 step process in which the matrix is converted into a nicer form, and then the QR algorithm is used.

Understanding the power method is a good place to start from because it's intuition informs most of the other methods in some way or another.